# How to trigger mini layout page in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning, mini-page-layout

At the moment in classic Salesforce, I'm able to trigger the mini layout page of a record by doing the following:

```
//normal layout of record
https://na34.salesforce.com/{record-id}

//mini layout of record
https://na34.salesforce.com/{record-id}/m
```

In Lightning, the normal layout would be the following:

```
https://na34.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/{record-id}/view
```

I've already tried to change the endpoint from view to m and compact. Neither are valid though. Hoping someone else might know how to do this in Lightning.